# country_select display full country name on show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, rubygems

I use the gem 'country_select' to choose a country for a form on my rails app however when I go to a show or index action I see the stored value. Is there a method to convert the value to a full name string of the country?

```
[AU] => "Australia"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation includes how to get [exactly what you want](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select#getting-the-country-name-from-the-countries-gem).

```
country = ISO3166::Country[country_code]
country.translations[I18n.locale.to_s] || country.name
```

Comment: Thanking you kindly for that

Comment: this code does not work anymore. I tried to use it and i have this error  `undefined method  translations for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [country_select](https://github.com/countries/country_select#getting-the-country-name-from-the-countries-gem) documentation I place this in `application_helper.rb`:

```rb
def country_name(country_code)
  unless country_code.nil? || country_code == ""
    country = ISO3166::Country[country_code]
    country.translations[I18n.locale.to_s] || country.common_name || country.iso_short_name
  end
end
```

and use it in the view like so:

```
<%= country_name(@user.country_code) %>
```