# How to convert the country_select's country code to country name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This same question has already been posted on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32193447/country-select-display-full-country-name-on-show-action) but hasn't been solved and I don't really understand the readme in country_select github page.

I hope you understand :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its given in the docs

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

 # Assuming country_select is used with User attribute `country_code`
 # This will attempt to translate the country name and use the default
 # (usually English) name if no translation is available
 def country_name
   country = ISO3166::Country[country_code]
   country.translations[I18n.locale.to_s] || country.name
 end
end
```

Here is the link https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select#getting-the-country-name-from-the-countries-gem

**UPDATE**

In your `SurfSchool` model

```
def country_name
   c = ISO3166::Country[self.country]
   return c.translations[I18n.locale.to_s] || c.name
end
```

So anywhere in your controller or view

```
@surfschool.country_name // this will give country name
```

Comment: Thanks but this is what I'm referring to that I don't understand from the docs.

Comment: If you see the code. `country_select` has a dependency for a gem called "country". It uses that gem for country names. `ISO3166::Country` is called from that gem. `ISO3166` is a module which has `Country` module which contains all the names as an hash with country codes as the keys and the translations as their values which in next line u can use `I18n` to get the your current language translation for the name. I hope its clear.

Comment: My current code now is @surfschools.country which display the country code. What changes do I need to have then?

Comment: Is `SurfSchool` a model?

Comment: Yes it's a model. My code works perfect except that it shows the 2 letter country code.

Comment: So I pasted the code in my SurfSchool model, then the @surfschool.country_name to the view, then I also change the strong params in controller to country_name but I got an error saying "undefined local variable or method `country_code' for #<SurfSchool:0x9159648>"

Comment: can u paste the error stack and also your model, controller & view

Comment: Now it works. The mistake I made was I used the country_code instead of your self.country. Can you tell me why you use the self.country instead of the country_code that is in the docs? Thanks!

Comment: Because your model store country code in field `country`, so `self.country` returns the country code for your current instance.

Comment: No problem, glad i could help :)